# What does: ERROR: tuple offset out of range: 0 mean?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgis

It seems (but I can't tell for sure) that after I added a postgis indexed column (USING gist) to my database last week, I have been seeing a lot of those errors:

```
ERROR: tuple offset out of range: 0
```

The errors occur on all kinds of queries, also some that does not use those columns, and hence shouldn't use that index right?

Anyways my question is: What does that error message mean, and could it have something to do with postgis, or am I off track?

I'm on postgresql 9.3 and postgis 2.1

Comment: Does rebuilding the index (or even all indexes on the table) help?

Comment: Looks like it's failing a TID bitmap sanity check in `src/backend/nodes/tidbitmap.c`. So I suspect you may have a damaged visibilty map or freespace map for the relation. A `CLUSTER` or `VACUUM FULL` is probably wise.

Comment: Thanks - but I have no idea what that means still - I'll try a vacuum full as suggested. Why might this have happened?

Comment: Okay it worked, it solved the problem. The issue started to occur out of "nothing" the other day (the new postgis indexes had been running for several days before). Can you by any means give me a hint on what might have caused this, so I can try to prevent having downtime doing a `VACUUM FULL` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all caused by the bug described and fixed in this release: http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1506/

It caused us a lot of trouble!